# Color and shape options in Annotation box for html annotation with HTML not HTML5, CSS and Java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML I've as of now for this one.

```
<div  id="box" class="box " >    
<table style = "border=0; cellpadding=0 cellspacing=4">
        <tr style=" border=0;">
            <td style="border=0;"><a type="button" class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="cancelPopup();"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border=0;">
            <td style="border=0;">
                <textarea id="text_area" placeholder="Input here..." name="comment" style="height:90px;width:325px; background: #fcfbf7"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr style="border=0;">
            <td style="border=0;" >
                Categories:
                <select name="commentStatus">
                    <option value="annotation1">Annotation1</option>
                    <option value="annotation2">annotation2</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                Amended: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">
            </td>
        </tr>   
        <tr style="border=0;">
            <td  style="border=0;">
                <div class="mceActionPanel"  style="">
                    <div style="float: right">
                        <input type="submit" style="background:#E6E6E6" id="insert" name="Save" value="Save"/>
                    </div>      
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

[image: what I've right now]

I want to include color choosing option and also a shape for the highlighted area. I tried as shown in above picture what I did right now, which is not the exact case I'm looking for.

below is the similar case I'm looking for and want to include the color options and shape options for user.

[image].

Can anyone help me with HTML and CSS how I can initiate those two boxes as a drop down with colors and shapes.

it would be great if someone can also give JS to highlight them back in html document on choosing the color and shapes.

Thanks,
--Sree

Answer (score 0):

html5 introduced a color selector.
It may not be exactly what your looking for but it should be close to it.

```html
<input type="color" placholder="test"/>
```

As for the shape selection

I think adding a unicode or image to each option would be the simplest approach:

```css
.shapes {
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.shapes option {
  height: 20px;
  direction: rtl;
}
.shapes option span
```

```html
<select class="shapes">
  <option>Shape1 ✵</option>
  <option>Shape2 ✩ </option>
  <option>Shape2 ➜</option>
  <option>Shape2 ◺</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you for your inputs, but we are planning not to use HTML 5 because it might not be compatible with all the browsers and there might be small small issues.

Comment: coming to shapes, I'm planning to give flexibility to user to define his own shape, with some CSS attributes. Then we will be using that to shape the highlighted selected content.

Comment: any inputs how I can initiate on these items would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you solution is so spesific as to not use html5 you should **absolutely** mention this in the question as this is a huge constraint!